# Windows, UAC and file copy

Tags: windows, uac

I recently upgraded my work computer to Windows 8 and I am an administrator on the computer.
I have left the UAC on.

I have started to notice some odd behavior when attempting to copy .exe files to network
shares.

The shares are provided through a Linux server running samba. I have write access to these shares because I set it up this way, as well if I copy something like a PDF file it copies without a problem.

But with .exe files Windows starts to act really strangely.
If I attempt to copy something from my local PC to the network share I receive an error similar to the one shown below:
[image]

If I attempt to run an .exe from the same share I get an error from Windows stating that the network path is unavailable.

[image]

I have added the "EnableLinkedConnections" registry key that makes mapped drives available to all users and this has not solved the problem.

It seems to occur only with files that require elevation to execute. So .exe files are the main file type I am having issues with. PDF's, txt files, word docs, etc, all seem to be fine.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this? Is this normal behavior when the UAC is enabled in Windows?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Cheers

Comment: Playing with it a little more it appears to only be with certain files under certain directories. I will have to dig into the potential differences between the directories themselves

Comment: Have you asked the administrator of the Linux box to ensure that s/he is running the latest version of Samba? Windows 8 shipped with SMB 3.0 which maybe causing an incompatibility with some non-Microsoft implementations of SMB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2709568

Comment: This is a good point. I had factored this in as a potential problem. However, it is a little strange because under Windows 7 which uses SMB2 I get the same behavior on the same files/folders that are affected under Windows 8. The version of SMB that is running is 3.6.9. I will consider this as a potential factor to what is causing the problem.